# Gaussian Integrals and Pseudo-Anosov Maps

Tags: pr.probability, gt.geometric-topology, ds.dynamical-systems

The hep-th section of arXiv if often filled with beautiful semi-rigorous computations on Mathematics.  However sometimes it is very difficult to understand what is being stated.

Here I take from: [Aspects of 3d-3d Correspondence](http://arxiv.org/abs/1510.05011) by Gang + Kim + Romo + Yamazaki.  They show the asyptotics of a certain Gaussian integral is related to the entropy of a pseudo-Anosov map on the torus.  In particular they work this out for the case $\mathrm{S} \, \mathrm{T}^k$ where one $\mathrm{S}$ is the flip and $\mathrm{T}$ is the shear.

[image]

Their Gaussian integral the partition function of some 3D gauge theory with no mathematical definition, so I have no way of checking their conjecture for other maps.

Are there conjectures of this kind on the math literature connecting Gaussians and hyperbolic maps?  How do I get a formula to check for general maps in $\pi_1 (\mathbb{T}^2 \backslash \{ pt\})$ on the once-punctured torus.